Consumiendo servicio REST JSON con PHP
Estoy intentando hacer en php un listado de expedientes tomando los datos de una  API REST.
El tema es que cuando hago la consulta me dice que hay 41 registros, pero al querer mostrarlos solo me muestra 2 registros.
Les paso el código, a ver en que me estoy equivocando.
Muchas Gracias.
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
CURLOPT_URL => '......',
CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'GET',
CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
'Authorization: Bearer '.$permiso,
),
));
$res = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
$dat = json_decode($res, true);
print_r($res);
?>
<br><br>
aca el array<br><br>
<?php
for( $i=0; $i<count($dat); $i++){
$ubicacion = $dat['data'][$i]['attributes']['ubicacion_de_expte_c'];
$estado = $dat['data'][$i]['attributes']['estado_tarea_c'];
echo'
    id: '.$i.'<br>
    Estado: '.str_replace("_", " ", $estado).'<br>
    Ubicación de Exp: '.str_replace("_", " ", $ubicacion).'<br><br><br><br>';
}
?>


Hola Alejandro, si ya lo resolviste, crea una respuesta. No es correcto agregar la respuesta en la pregunta. PD: Sin poder ver el JSON es imposible saber si vienen paginados o no.

Ok, igualmente muchas Gracias Marcos

Ya lo resolví, les dejo el código que use. Soy nuevo en esto y voy saltando de opciones en base a prueba y error. Será como dice Marcos que los datos vienen paginados? si es así confírmenme así aprendo mas.
foreach ((array)$dat['data'] as $valor) {
    $ingreso = $valor['attributes']['date_entered'];
    $name = $valor['attributes'] 
    echo "
    fecha de Ingreso: $ingreso<br>
    id expediente: $name<br>
    <br><br>";
}

